# AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute '_name_to_fitted_passthrough

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, streamlit

I am predicting the Car Price Prediction probability. While deploying the model using streamlit it show this error:
AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute '_name_to_fitted_passthrough'
That's my code:

```
transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [
    ('tnf1', OneHotEncoder(categories=ohe.categories_), ['name','company','fuel_type'])
], remainder = 'passthrough')
lr = LinearRegression()
pipe = Pipeline([ ('trf1', transformer), ('lr', lr) ])
```

When user input all information then after click on Predict button this error will fire. Chat gpt only gives solution to reinstall scikit-learn, pandas, streamlit and also tell to downgrade libraries and to check these libraries compatibility issues.
I've do all these steps but still i got error.
If anybody have solution then please reply me :)